# how come we are able to bind the function in constructor of react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

We hear that when a class component is initialized, the constructor is the first function called, and then how come inside the constructor we are able to access and bind to a function which is defined later in the class 
i.e. to ask, how come we are able to access this.fn, inside constructor?

```js
import React from 'react';
class A extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.a = 1;
    this.fn = this.fn.bind(this);
  }
  fn(){
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `class` declaration initializes the prototype object. By the time the constructor is called, the prototype is ready to be used.

Comment: This means that constructor is called after whole of the class code is run

Comment: Yes. The `class` syntax is just a cosmetic wrapper around a normal function declaration (the constructor) and code to initialize properties on the prototype object. So the `class` code "runs" before any call to the constructor is made (that is, before any object is created).

Comment: I think there's a duplicate question out there but I can't find it; I'll type my comments in as an answer.

Comment: sure!, I couldn't find either therefore asked

Comment: anyway the question will be informational to newbees!,, its concise and and your answer as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` declaration is itself a "pretty" wrapper around the declaration of a constructor function and the initialization of the constructor's prototype object. (There are a couple of other features, but for our purposes here that's what it is.)

Thus the `class` code itself represents executable code, not just a static declaration. The prototype object is initialized therefore before any calls to the constructor are actually made. When the constructor is called, the prototype properties (like your `fn()` method) are ready to be used.